# Magento: Order detail page is not showing

Tags: magento

Order details page isn't showing any data, `left bar` , `header` , `footer` are present on the page. I enabled error log but there isn't error.

If I change theme to other theme, I can see details but when I change it to hellowired theme, nothing is there.

I don't understand whats wrong going on, what I'm supposing is some other person played with code or changed something which is causing this issue, and now I'm totally unable to understand where to proceed from.

Its simply complicated. Without any error how can I reach at that point in Magento where there are so many files in it with vast and complicated structure.

Any help would act as pain relief :P. Is there anyone who can suggest anything.

Answer (score 0):

If it's working with default theme, that means your custom theme "helloweird" may have something wrong in the layout files.

If you are referring to the checkout page you should look in the file

`app/design/frontend/helloweird/helloweird/layout/checkout.xml` .

If you are referring to account order history details then you should look in the `customer.xml`

The path to the layout folder of your theme may differ. 
You will not receive errors if the layout xml files have something wrong.

Comment: I just copied customer.xml from working theme to hellowired theme but its still blank.

Comment: I don't have a magento file structure in front, so you should look inside customer.xml for the order history block and check the parent phtml file if it has and echo getChildHtml of order details block

Comment: I found <block type="sales/order_history" name="sales.order.history">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="sales.order.history.info" as="info" translate="label">
                    <label>Order History Info</label>
                </block>
            </block> inside sales.xml

Comment: When I enabled template paths from admin, then on another theme it shows info.phtml's path is from default parent theme. But on hellowired there isn't any path that says info.phtml.

Comment: Inside customer.xml , its  <block type="customer/account_dashboard_info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info" as="info" template="customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml"/>

Comment: but original path is \public_html\app\design\frontend\default\default\template\deliverydate\order\info.phtml

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to check `checkout.xml` FROM `app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/layout`

if it's contain `checkout_onepage_success` `block` if not then you have to copy these block from `base`

```
<checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
        <label>One Page Checkout Success</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/onepage_success" name="checkout.success" template="checkout/success.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_success>
```

let me know if you have still problem

Comment: This block is already there inside checkout.xml. I downloaded same theme again and pasted it inside design folder, and its still not working.

Comment: can you share me your theme url where you have downloaded?

Comment: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/06/03/download-a-free-magento-theme-hellowired/